# XMLHTTPRequest onreadystatechange not working

Tags: javascript, events, xmlhttprequest, electron, onreadystatechange

Im trying to send an asynchronous post request to my "server" in my electron application but the callback function `onreadystatechange` does not get called after any change. I suspect that the problem is the event-handler for the html button click event or the scope of the variable `xmlHttp`.

```
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

document.getElementById('bttnAddUser').addEventListener('click', () => {
    let user = {
        firstname: 'name',
        lastname: 'name',
        username: 'username',
        created: Date.now().toString(),
        lastLogin: Date.now().toString()
    }

    xmlHttp.open('POST', 'http:/localhost:3000/add', true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        // does not get called
        console.log('accessed change callback');
        console.log(this.readyState + this.status);
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            ipcRenderer.send('open-new-window', 'index2.html');
        }
    }

    xmlHttp.send(JSON.stringify(user));
});
```

Comment: Put `var xmlHttp = ...` inside the function, not as a global variable.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your code is working in principle. The URL is missing a second forward slash after `http:`. Make sure you add the event listener **after the DOM is loaded** (you may listen for `DOMContentLoaded` to achieve that). When you log `this.readyState + this.status`, they will get added as numbers, but that's just an aside. Add another `console.log(..)` into the click event listener to find out if it gets called at all.